# Setting startup script without update-rc.d

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, yocto-project

I am currently working on a Yocto based raspeberrypi which doesn't have update-rc.d (or almost anything for that matter) and I'm trying to make a script run at startup. I added it in /etc/init.d but that alone is not enough apparently.
Also I am aware on a normal Linux distro you could add it in /etc/rc.local or even .bashrc but these files are not present here and I even tried creating them myself and calling my script but no luck.

What other solution might there be ?

Comment: Have you looked at anacron?

Answer (score 0):

For the RPi, I believe you want to use `chkconfig`. ( depending on your distro )

Place the script in `init.d` with the appropriate header

```
# chkconfig: 2345 20 80
# description: <some description>
```

and then use

```
chkconfig myscriptname on
```